Ubuntu 22 going straight to BIOS then bypassing encrypted drive
used to have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS drive which was locked requiring password (full system encryption).
However now it boots straight to BIOS, bypassing that password requirement.
The hardware appears fine and everything else seems normal (such as passwords to enter ubuntu).
This may related to this question: Boots straight to BIOS
But I am such a newbie, I don't know.  Please advise.

Encryption is not a mere password requirement that can be "bypassed". If it truly "boots straight to BIOS" then the disk is not loaded, seems still encrypted, and nothing bypassed anyway. Your link is about somebody who booted to GRUB, not to BIOS, so how is that relevant? I doubt we can help much if your question does not accurately and clearly describe what is happening.

Your description highlights a machine specific firmware setting or problem; as you have the booting of the machine (which is handled by machine firmware) not booting the OS on disk, but going instead to firmware settings (BIOS). Your details imply a problem with unstated hardware and that machine's firmware.

The BIOS (or whatever bootloader you're using) does not understand, and cannot decrypt your encrypted disk, so instead of a bootable image, the bootloader just sees junk (encrypted data). Unless you can configure the bootloader to mount a decrypting overlaying filesystem, you're out of luck (try another working Linux machine to mount the disk, make unencrypted backup, test backup, wipe the disk, restore backup, recondider use case for full disk encryption in your environment)
